# RequireJS - required items always return undefined

Tags: requirejs

I have never used RequireJS before, so any help would be appreciated.
I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        data-main="CustomScripts/market-need" 
        src="CustomScripts/require.js"></script>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>
<body>
etc...
</body>
</html>
```

I have the following JavaScript defined in `CustomScripts/market-need.js`.

```
(function(){
    requirejs.config({ baseUrl: 'CustomScripts' });

    require(['mndataservice'],
        function (mndataservice) {
            mndataservice.getListData();
        });
})();
```

And the following code saved in `CustomScripts/mndataservice.js`.

```
define([], function () {
    function getListData() {
            alert("Hit");
        }

    return
    {
        getListData: getListData
    };
});
```

Whenever I run the above, `mndataservice` is undefined when it hits the `mndataservice.getListData();` line in the `market-need.js`. This worked at one point, I and I cannot find the error I have made for the life of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change:

```
function (mndataservice) {
    mndataservice.getListData();
});
```

to:

```
function (mndataservice) {
    this.mndataservice.getListData();
});
```

and then also replace the contents of mndataservice.js with:

```
var mndataservice = {
    getListData: function () {
        alert("Hit");
    }
};
```

I think it will fix it for you.

Update:

Simply changing mndataservice.js to:

```
define([], function () {
    return {
        getListData: function () {
            alert("Hit");
        }
    }
});
```

should fix it. Do not add "this." in the other function.

**Update**

Following up on your question below that asked why your example didn't work and mine did. The reason yours didn't work - your code is actually doing this:

```
define([], function () {
    function getListData() {
            alert("Hit");
        }

    return;
    {
        getListData: getListData
    };
});
```

Note the semicolon right after the `return` keyword. Though not in your code, it gets inserted automatically by Javascript's [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/12/basic-javascript-part-6-automatic-semicolon-insertion/) which causes it to return *undefined* rather than the object.

Moving the open curly brace up to same line as `return` fixes it!

Comment: Ok, but my intent was to use the revealing module pattern with the mndataservice. Any explanation as to why that was incorrect? I was looking at the examples here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define

Comment: See update above. I think it will fix it with only a minor change to mndataservice.js required, which still uses that revealing module pattern.

Comment: The final example doesn't work. I don't like the fact that using RequireJS is descending into magic. Say the words in this order, sacrifice a chicken, maybe it will work! ;-)

Comment: That's strange. I tried the code in at least 3 different browsers (Chrome,Safari,Firefox) and it seems to work. Also on IE earlier. Have you tried refreshing your cache?

Comment: Sorry, I had kept `this` where you said to remove it. I want you to know I am very thankful, but I don't understand *why* my `define` does not work and your `define` does. I thought those were basically the same.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. If you can give any explanation regarding the "why" I would be grateful.

Comment: Are you asking why does Javascript have the automatic semicolon insertion mechanism? I'm not really sure of the reasoning, but its effect is to make semicolons optional, as long as one separates statements with <cr>'s, but with horribly horrible unintended consequences like the example you showed. It can really bite programmers like me with backgrounds in C style languages who are used to being able to place opening braces either on the same or next line and have it work the same either way. I would recommend reading the Automatic Semicolon Insertion link above for more info.

Comment: Also, for programming in Javascript, I would highly recommend the [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) tool, which can catch all kinds of Javascript errors depending on which options one selects.